# Node.js: How to route website map

Tags: node.js

I am newbie in Node.js; sorry if my question is dumb:

I wanted to return `index.html` from server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/elements/hello-world.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/elements/hello-world.html'));
});

app.listen(1337);
```

But there are many assets in the html file that are stored with the appropriate structure on local server. For example, for returning `/elements/hello-world.html`, it is sufficient to return `hello-world.html` under elements folder which itself is in root.

But it is not reasonable to write a route for every asset (like `css`es, `image`s, etc) in `index.html`.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you want to serve static files,to serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

taken from the official express docs [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks, but what is public directory?

Comment: is where the files you want to serve are, in your case could be the "elements"  folder

Comment: I added `app.use(express.static('elements'));` and removed the route. It cannot be found now. Am I missing something?

Comment: you should be able to access it like this http://localhost:1337/hello-world.html, the 'element' folder shouldn't go in the route, since everything on that folder is now public

Answer (score 1):

The solution is `app.use`, like (CoffeeScript):

```
app.use express.static(public_dir)
app.use '/js', express.static(path.join(public_dir, '/js'))
app.use '/css', express.static(path.join(public_dir, '/css'))
app.use '/images', express.static(path.join(public_dir, '/images'))
app.use '/fonts', express.static(path.join(public_dir, '/fonts'))
app.use '/svgs', express.static(path.join(public_dir, '/svgs'))
```

In the index.html we pull resources like

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/primus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app_090.js"></script>
```

I'm actually not sure if that answers your question, but this is how resource type routing is done in Express.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the express static module.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Create a folder called public in your nodejs root folder, put your index.html and your elements folder inside it.

Now when you load http://localhost/index.html and http://localhost/elements/hello-world.html it should work without any issues.